# Change font and font size on wizard page information text box in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I need to change the font and probably the font size on the wizard page *"Information"* for the text box where the text is displayed specified via the parameter `InfoBeforeFile` in section `[Languages]`. The reason for changing the font is that the file content displayed in the text box is produced using a monospaced font like `Courier New`.

In the *Inno Setup Help* I looked through *Support Classes References* to find an answer but I was unsuccessful.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `Font` property of `WizardForm.InfoBeforeMemo`.

```pascal
[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.InfoBeforeMemo.Font.Name := 'Courier New';
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Martin: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. My problem is solved!